# How can I mirror the display from an iOS device to an Apple TV?

Tags: ios, appletv, airplay

Is there a way to mirror the display of an iPod Touch or iPad to the Apple TV using AirPlay?

I know I can do it for Applications that support it, but for presentations it's often useful to just mirror the whole display, e.g. when wanting to show something in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iPad 2 and a iOS developer's account (or patience until this fall) you can try the hot new iOS 5 feature:

**[AirPlay Mirroring for iPad 2](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with a wired solution that doesn't use AirPlay, you'd be best off just connecting the device to the TV itself (not the Apple box). Cables/adapters for that (I haven't tested any of these):

[iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch 4G       ==>    HDMI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0048BY38C)
[iPad/iPhone 4/iPod Touch 4G    ==>    VGA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CGOTJW)
[iPad/iPod Touch/iPhone/iPod    ==>    Component/RCA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C04PAA)

Comment: Problem with them is that they only output certain content and have to be supported by the Application. I'm looking for something that mirrors everything, like what Steve Jobs uses at his Keynotes (although I guess that's Apple Internal)

Comment: @Michael If you're playing a movie or a presentation, these should be fine. I haven't seen these used with Safari, so good point there. I would look into some kind of a VNC client that lets you view your iOS device on your Mac, and connect the Mac to the TV/projector. Never seen this kind of software, but it might exist.

Comment: @Michael There is no way to straight-up mirror the display from anything but an iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

On the same line of a wired solution, not airplay, there is an app available in cydia if you are jailbroken called TVOut2 Mirror that works good.

http://tvout2.webs.com/